# What is the total weight of the minimal spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory

Here are the weights for the edges in a weighted complete graph. The numbers in the table give the weight
of the edge joining each pair of vertices. First use Prim’s algorithm to find a minimal spanning tree in this
weighted graph. Then use Kruskal’s algorithm to achieve the same thing.

PICTURE of table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Olpp.png)

What is the total weight of the minimal spanning tree?

**I have no idea how to approach this question or what the question is asking of me.**

Comment: What about googling what these algorithms mean? You even have Youtube video's explaining it.

Comment: I understand vaguely the algorithms, however my graphs for both of them are extremely messy and I am not sure they are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prim:

1. start with a,
2. find minimum weight of connected element to a, that is c (4),
3. find minimum weight of connected element to {a, c}, that is f (11)
4. continue to find h (5),
5. now it becomes slightly more difficult because you also have to look vertically, but find: d (17), b (12), e (9), g (31)

Double check if I did correctly and add the numbers. 
If you needed the edges also, do slightly more administration..

Kruskal looks for minimum weight edges and adds as long as no cycle is formed.

We'd find (ac), (fh), (be), (cf), (bd), (df), (fg) respectively.

Comment: after step 2  (a,c) weight of 4, why can't you go to (f,h) weight 5?

Comment: That is allowed in Kruskal, not in Prim

Answer (score 0):

To understand this question you need to know:

Kruskal's algorithm (you should do, or else it would make no sense for you to be doing/have been set this question)

Prim's algorithm (for the same reason above)

Once you have used these two algorithms to find a minimum spanning tree for each (the two minimum spanning trees can be equal), then add up the weights of all the edges of that derived spanning tree. This will be its total weight. If the spanning tree derived from each of the algorithm above is different, unless stated/implied otherwise, you'd use the spanning tree with the smaller total weight, as the entire idea behind a minimum spanning tree is to find the shortest one (most of the time).

Comment: The trees can be different, the minimum numbers can't.

Comment: ^good point, my answer did miss that out